# Grails: Invoking one taglib from within another with own namespaces

Tags: grails

Using some tagLibs with own namespace

Something like

```
class FirstTagLib
    static namespace =  "myns"
    ...
    def first = {  attrs, body ->
    ...
    }
```

/

```
class SecondTagLib {

    static namespace = "myns"


    def second = { attrs, body ->  

        out << myns.first(..)
    }
```

How can I invoke this taglib in another taglib? Normally the g. would work for taglibs which do not have an own namespace.

The [documentation states](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#namespaces) that:

> Tags within namespaces can be invoked as methods using the namespace
>   as a prefix to the method call

In my case this ends up in error: 
*No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.first() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [., strong]...*

Comment: Are you reusing the same namespace in two different tag libraries? I think that may be an issue.

Comment: what arguments are you using for `out << myns.first(..)`? it should correspond to signature. Also try renaming your `first` method is something context-specific, because *GroovyPage.first()* no-arg already exists

Comment: @injecteer I am using other names for the methods. I used first and second for the example...

Comment: @JoshuaMoore How can using one namespace be an issue accross taglibs?

Comment: @Armand this was a bit misleading from your side. If you want to conceal the top-secret details of your code, then `someMethod()` is way better than `first()`, as the later one implies the specific meaning for groovy sdk. Especially if you post the `stacktrace` with it! Anyway, I tend to agree with @JoshuaMoore, using 1 namespace for 1 taglib should work like charm, as Grails is not so smart to combine several taglibs for the same not-default NS together.

Comment: @Injecteer this was a problem of signature. If you can make your comment an answer I could accept the answer